# Promises on non-supported browsers

Tags: javascript, android, es6-promise

My web page is potentially loaded by some old browsers (specifically, in an Android app with WebView, which may still be used by some pretty old devices)... not that many so I don't want to go to too much trouble to support them fully, but I at least want the page to load.  So, I'd rather not resort to transpilers etc to back everything fully backward compatible.

So how do I make my code "safe" to use on the older browsers?  Those parts of my code that use promises are "optional" in the sense that if they are not accessible then the page will still be of use.  So I'd like some way of including promises in my code without it breaking things for older browsers.

Is it enough to put these parts inside a check for promise support, like `if (window.Promise) { myPromise = getMeAPromise(); mPromise.then(...).catch(...); }` so that these parts would never be reached by the interpreter?  Or is there a compilation process that would still cause this to fail on a non-supported browser?

Answer (score 6):

So long as you test for support in a way that won't fail if it's not there, you don't need to worry. Your `if (window.Promise)` fits that definition, but if it were me, I'd use `if (typeof Promise !== "function")`. So perhaps:

```
var hasPromiseSupport = typeof Promise === "function";
```

...and then `if (hasPromiseSupport)` around the optional bits.

All of that said: There are complete Promise polyfills available, so you could conditionally include one:

```
if (typeof Promise !== "function") {
    document.write('<script src="some-promise-polyfill.js"><\/script>');
}
```

...and then you'd have promises. (Yes, to my mind this is the one remaining valid use case for `document.write`.)

Comment: Really helpful, thanks.  Please could you include a link to a good promise polyfill?  Just needs to be "good enough", without adding too much to the code size.  Thanks again.

Comment: @drmrbrewer: [This one](https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise) is linked from the [MDN Promise page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). I haven't looked at it though.